# Command to open a URL

Tags: command-line

Is there a command I can use in Bash that will open a specific URL in the default browser?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There's a command that knows about your default browser:

```
xdg-open http://google.com
```

This will also work for *every other type* of URI (Uniform Resource Identifier), like images - which will automatically open with eog, openoffice documents, and so on, and also on filesystem paths (`xdg-open /tmp/foobar.png`).

There is also

```
xdg-email team@stackexchange.com
```

and

```
xdg-mime query default text/html
```

To find out what application is going to be used.

You can set your preffered application by going to *System → Preferences → Preferred Applications*:

[image]

These utilities are part of the [freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/) specification, so you can use them in your applications - and it's going to work on all of the desktops that adhere to the [spec](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mime-actions-spec).

Comment: echo **`alias open=xdg-open`** >> ~/.bashrc, highly recommended.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `xdg-open` like so:

```
xdg-open http://askubuntu.com/
```

From the [XDG-OPEN man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html):

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a
>          URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web
>          browser.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't necessarily want to use the default browser, you can call any browser program directly and give the URL as argument, for example:

```
chromium-browser https://youtube.com
```

or

```
firefox https://youtube.com
```

Answer (score 3):

`gnome-open` works as well as `xdg-open` but neither knows what to do with naked domain.

So `gnome-open http://askubuntu.com` works but not `gnome-open askubuntu.com`.

Here is a small function to make it easier to type and accept the stripped down domain name.

```
function go { gnome-open http://$1 ; }
```

Paste the above in your command line, hit enter and try it out. If you like it you can save it to your .bash_aliases or .bashrc file, then `source ~/.bash_aliases` (assuming it is in your home directory) and it will be persistent for that session and all new sessions.

So now we just type `go askubuntu.com` and wallah!

Comment: `gnome-open` is not found on Ubuntu 23.10 with GNOME 45

Answer (score 1):

Using `x-www-browser URL` will open the browser or a new tab at the given URL

Comment: `x-browser` is not found in Ubuntu 23.10