# Terminal command to open URL's in default and non-default browser

Tags: command-line, firefox, google-chrome

[I found this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19919/command-to-open-a-url) about how to open a URL in your default browser using the Terminal. Basically, you use the command

```
xdg-open http://google.com
```

My default browser is Firefox. But lets say that I wanted to open a specific website in Chrome, instead of Firefox. Is there a command to open it in Chrome instead of Firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always just type `google-chrome www.askubuntu.com` to open our favorite site, for example.