# is there a way to open browser using terminal?

Tags: bash, browser

Is there a way to open Chrome (or other browser) using terminal?

Something like: `$ chrome www.google.com` ?

Comment: Do you want to open it to a specific web page or just open the browser?

Answer (score 27):

From: [Terminal command to open URL's in default and non-default browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288757/terminal-command-to-open-urls-in-default-and-non-default-browser) (which I don't think is a duplicate)

If you want to open Chrome to a specific URL, just run

```
google-chrome www.example.com
```

To open your default browser to a specific URL, run

```
xdg-open www.example.com
```

---

If you need to run Chrome and close the terminal window afterward, run

```
google-chrome http://www.google.com </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

`>/dev/null 2>&1` will prevent messages from the browser to be outputted to the terminal's window; `&` will put the process into the background and `disown` will remove the job / process from the job list, preventing a SIGHUP signal to be propagated to it.

To do this with another browser simply replace `google-chrome` with that other browser's executable name.

Comment: Thanks! But there is a slight difference comparing to using a launcher. I will kill the process if I close terminal or ctrl+c. It's not a big deal though.

Comment: @kos is it alright if I add this to my answer?

Comment: Sure, but use `google-chrome http://www.google.com </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown`, because `stdout` and `stderr` get printed to the terminal without the redirections

Comment: @kos Is it correct?

Comment: Almost: `>/dev/null 2>&1` prevents `stdout` and `stderr` to be printed to the terminal, `</dev/null` "closes" `stdin`, but to be honest that's not really necessary; `&` puts the process into the background and `disown` removes the process from the `bash` instance's jobs list, which prevents the SIGHUP signal sent to `bash` instance upon the terminal closure to be propagated to it

Comment: @kos you should probably edit that in.

Comment: Done :) see how it fits.

Comment: @kos Yeah, that's fine!

Answer (score 5):

You can open Google Chrome from terminal very surprisingly by running

```
google-chrome
```

You can also start Firefox by running

```
firefox
```

And you can add an URL as a parameter to open it too.

```
firefox www.askubuntu.com
```

Comment: Awesome! But there is a slight difference comparing to using a launcher. I will kill the process if I close terminal or ctrl+c. It's not a big deal though.

Comment: once I refreshed page a bit of your answer was gone, but I think it's useful to keep it: `nohup google-chrome &`

Comment: That does not work. It still closes Chrome. You may need to use `screen`.

Answer (score 5):

`sensible-browser` seems to be the option you're looking for. This will run the web browser set as default on your system, you can also pass parameters on it in order to run the web browser and open the given website(s).

### Usage:

In a terminal, drop the next and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>

```
sensible-browser
```

### Passing parameters:

The next command will open [youtube.com](http://youtube.com) in your preferred web browser:

```
sensible-browser youtube.com
```

### How to set my favorite web browser flavour from the terminal?

Simply drop the next command in a terminal, hit <kbd>Return</kbd> and choose wisely:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

In the next example I am choosing `luakit` as my default browser. You can change your default web browser as many times as you wish.

```
geppettvs@T400:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
There are 5 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/konqueror              30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/luakit                 10        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/xlinks2                69        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 4
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/luakit to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in manual mode
```

### Unattaching from terminal

If you wish to keep your web browser running just after you close your terminal, simply add an ampersand symbol at the end of your command:

```
sensible-browser [parameters] &
```

Good luck!

Comment: Nice, but without `disown` closing the terminal SIGHUPs it; you want to add `disown` and to redirect at least `stdout` and `stderr` to avoid messages to be still outputted to the terminal (and maybe `stdin` for "formal correctness"): `sensible-browser [parameters] </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown`

Comment: Is "sensible-browser" supported all Linux flavors? Or is it just certain distributions like Debian, etc.?

Comment: AFAIK `sensible-browser` is available on every Ubuntu flavor. I haven't tried this on other Linux systems.